# BASH: Bracketing Parameters

Tags: bash

Simply, whats the fundamental difference between `$param` and `${param}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none.  It's for echoing a variable immediately followed by a string.

For example, if you have $param, but you want to have right after it, "lbs"

```
echo "${param}lbs"
```

Where as

```
echo "$paramlbs"
```

Would look for an incorrect variable name

Comment: Correct, but not just for `echo`, but any time you do that kind of concatenation.